# matplotlib colormaps: set_bad doesn't have an impact with collections

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colormap

I want to use the set_bad parameter of matplotlib colormaps to assign nan values a specific color. I created a colormap:

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, BoundaryNorm

cmap = ListedColormap(['green', 'yellow', 'red'])
norm = BoundaryNorm([0, 20, 70, 100], cmap.N)
```

Then I set the bad color to black:

```
cmap.set_bad(color="k")
```

To verify everything works as expected, I plotted an array as a test, and it works (the lower left quadrant is black):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(np.array([[10, 50], [np.nan, 70]]), cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
```

However, if I use this same colormap on collections, it doesn't work:

```
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
lc = LineCollection(([(0.1, 0.1), (0.1, 0.2)], [(0.2, .2), (0.2, .3)], [(0.3, .3), (0.3, .4)]))

lc.set_cmap(cmap)
lc.set_norm(norm)
lc.set_array(np.array([10, np.nan, 80]))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_collection(lc)
plt.draw()
```

The middle line gets an nan z-value and should be black, but it comes out green. It seems like nan is interpreted as 0 in this case.

Is this a bug or somehow intended? Does anyone know if it is possible to use set_bad with colormaps in a different way?

P.S.: I tested this with matplotlib 2.2 and 3.0, the result is the same

Comment: According to this bug report  https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9892, the "calls to `np.ma.masked_invalid` to convert user input with NaNs to masked arrays [...] were added to the highest-level parts of the API, like plot; they are not repeated at every stage below that." Maybe `LineCollections.set_array` is too low level to do this. This would mean the solution is to do the NaN masking yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As shown in [this issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9892) and commented by @EdSmith, `nan`s are not actually valid input to colormaps.

Instead, `nan`s are masked before the norm and colormap are applied to a `ScalarMappable`. This masking needs to be done by hand for `Collection`s.

```
.set_array(np.ma.masked_invalid([10., np.nan, 80.]))
```

Complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, BoundaryNorm
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

cmap = ListedColormap(['green', 'yellow', 'red'])
cmap.set_bad(color="k")
norm = BoundaryNorm([0, 20, 70, 100], cmap.N)

lc = LineCollection(([(0.1, 0.1), (0.1, 0.2)], [(0.2, .2), (0.2, .3)], [(0.3, .3), (0.3, .4)]))

lc.set_cmap(cmap)
lc.set_norm(norm)
lc.set_array(np.ma.masked_invalid([10., np.nan, 80.]))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_collection(lc)
plt.show()
```

[image]